# can not echo a function content inside file_get_contents

Tags: php, http, youtube, fopen, file-get-contents

Suppose this code prints `Youtube`:

```
<?php ytio_empt(); ?>
```

I want a dynamic way to echo the content of the above function in the place of `'YouTube'` in the following xml data:

```
$xmlData = file_get_contents( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'. 'YouTube' );
```

I have tried:

```
$xmlData = file_get_contents( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'. ytio_empt() );
```

But in vain, the `file_get_contents()` always fails to open stream.

P.S: Perhaps using HTML will work: to put `<?php ytio_empt(); ?>` in the place of `ytio_empt()` in `$xmlData`. I just don't know how to end PHP function and resume it later..

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump(ytio_empt());` ?

Comment: Thank you @Rizier123 . I have used this `var_dump(ytio_empt());` and it outputs `null` ..

Comment: And why should we then assume that it outputs `YouTube` :D? Your function doesn't return anything! I'm almost guessing that it prints Youtube BUT it doesn't RETURN it, right?

Comment: actually the full code for that function is:
`function ytio_empt() {
if(empty(get_option('ytio_username'))) {
    echo esc_attr( get_option('ytio_id') );
} else {
echo esc_attr( get_option('ytio_username') );
}
}`
And the user either fills the account username of the channel ID..
So it should echo a username ( ex YouTube ) or a channel ID ( ex UCF0pVplsI8R5kcAqgtoRqoA )
Thanks !

Comment: ^ See `echo` and not `return` so your function doesn't return anything! Just change echo to return :)

Comment: @Rizier123 : You rock dude. worked fine. 
please post this as an answer so that I can accept it.
Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Enjoy Easter :)

Comment: You too ^^ - enjoy !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you posted your function in the comments:

```
function ytio_empt() {

    if(empty(get_option('ytio_username'))) {
        echo esc_attr( get_option('ytio_id') );
      //^^^^
    } else {
        echo esc_attr( get_option('ytio_username') );
      //^^^^
    }

}
```

You will see you don't return the values you just print them! So in order to return them you simply have to change `echo` -> `return`.

And if you want to read more about return values see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php